# NetStream.Seek.Complete -?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, netstream, seek

Recently I have been playing with NetStream (once again..) and I found a strange thing I didn't observe before - now after NetStream.Seek.Notify another event fires: NetStream.Seek.Complete. Does anybody know when this was added and whether it works reliable for progressive streaming? I cannot seem to find anything about it in the reference... :-/
Thanks!